# iOS:Unable to send message to socket server using NSOutputStream connection drops when i try to send message

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets

**I have used following code to connect to the server**

```
- (void) initNetworkCommunication
{
  CFReadStreamRef readStream;
  CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
  CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL,(CFStringRef)URLBASE, 8080, &readStream, &writeStream);

  inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
  outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

  [inputStream setDelegate:self];
  [outputStream setDelegate:self];
  [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
  [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
  //    open input and output stream of socket to send and receive data
  [inputStream open];
  [outputStream open];
}
```

**and following code to send message using output stream**

```
-(IBAction)sendMessage{
   if (outputStream.hasSpaceAvailable) {
      [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
   }
}
```

but when I try to send message the connection drops and gives connection reset by remote peer.

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to send message the connection drops and gives connection
>   reset by remote peer.

The error text unequivocally states that the peer dropped the connection, so you have to look there for the reason rather than in the code above.